# Reversed method not rendering on Array

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, methods

Hello Stack Overflow!

I am learning methods in SWIFT and haven't been able to get the .reversed method to print out the actual reverse of an array on line 39. The .reverse method is working, however.

```
var characterClasses = ["Ranger", "Paladin", "Druid"]

characterClasses.append("Fairy")

characterClasses += ["Nymph", "Troll"]

characterClasses.remove(at: 2)


var reversedClasses = characterClasses.reversed()

print(reversedClasses)
```

I have tried rewriting the code and double checked that it matches what the instructor has typed into Xcode as well.

Any insight is appreciated! TY

Comment: Please paste code snippet in post directly, not image, see: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Will you please mark my answer as the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.reversed()` is actually returning a [ReversedCollection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1690025-reversed) instead of an array. Source

To turn this back into an array you can try:

```
print(characterClasses.reversed().map({ $0 }))
```

or

```
print(Array(characterClasses.reversed()))
```

Comment: `Array(characterClasses.reversed())`